# OpenMP, number of cores and accuracy of computation with random numbers

Tags: multithreading, random, parallel-processing, openmp

I have come across the interesting issue. I tried to evaluate the value of Pi using Monte-Carlo method with up to 12 CPU cores. And what I've found out was that accuracy of Pi has decreased in case of using 12 cores comparing to 4 cores.

Here are the results (which are stable, i.e. they are repetitive with each new run)

4 cores:

```
3.14159
```

12 cores:

```
3.1416
```

I have implemented OpenMP code with function

```
rand_r()
```

for random number generation (I know it is not very good, but it's ensured to be thread-safe). The seed had different value for each thread.

The full code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include "omp.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

unsigned seed;

int main()
{
double start = time(0);

int n, N;
double x, y;

N = 1<<30;
n = 0;

double pi;

#pragma omp parallel private(x, y, seed)
{
seed = 25234 + 17 * omp_get_thread_num();

#pragma omp for reduction(+:n)
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    x = (double) rand_r(&seed) / (double) RAND_MAX;
    y = (double) rand_r(&seed) / (double) RAND_MAX;

    if (x*x + y*y <= 1)
       n++;
}
}
pi = 4. * n / (double) (N);

cout << pi << endl;

double stop = time(0);

cout << (stop - start) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Is it reasonable to have worse accuracy while increasing the number of cores?
 Is it somehow connected with random number generation (in particular, with function rand_r)? 
Or is it about distribution of for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

Since the pseudo-random sequences in each thread are fixed and you are sum-reducing over integer values, i.e. no source of round-off errors present, the only thing that could influence the result when the number of threads changes are the correlations in the pseudo-random sequences.

`rand_r` is a linear congruential generator (LCG) with a relatively short period (relatively short given the large value of your `N`). LCGs are the worst choice for parallel processing since the future of the pseudo-random sequence is fully determined by the last output of the generator (there is no hidden state vector). Therefore, once one of the generators produces a value that matches the seed of one of the other generators, the two sequences become correlated and the contribution of the first sequence to the precision of the Monte Carlo process decreases. Another way to look at it is that the output of an LCG is a contiguous sub-sequence of some fixed cyclic sequence of numbers. The different seeds simply make the sub-sequences start at different points of the fixed one.

You should use better pseudo-random generators and make sure that the initial seeding does not result in correlated pseudo-random sequences. `random_r` is a good candidate as it implements a non-linear additive feedback generator. It's period should be long enough for 2<sup>30</sup> iterations. When in doubt, use a Mersenne Twister generator. It is available in the standard C++ library (since C++11).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I thought.